# Child class not found by the parent class

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I am experimenting with php class inheritance, I wrote the below code and got an uncaught error that the User class is not found. Please any help about where am going wrong will be fine.

the first block is the User class

```
         <?php
          class User{
                private $name;
                private $age;
            
                public function _construct($name, $age){
                $this->name = $name;
                $this->age = $age;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

**below is the customer class that inherit the user class.**

```
    <?php

    class Customer extends User{
        private $balance;
    
        public function __construct($name, $age, $balace) {
              parent::_construct($name, $age);
              $this->balance = $balace;
       }
         public function pay($amount){
        return $this->name ." paid $".$amount;
    }
    public function getBalance(){
        return $this->balance;
    }
}


$customer = new Customer("Matt", 23, 500);
echo $customer->getBalance();
```

Comment: Is all this code in one file?

Comment: You have to include  include('User.php');  the User class file into Customer class

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code by implementing it in a single file. It works fine.

If you are having 2 files for both classes, you need to include the `User` class file into the `Customer` class file like below.

```php
require_once('User.php');
```

Comment: Thanks Bro for your help, i appreciate